# Query posts filter not working

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have created one custom post type which name is `villa`. In this post type I have added five post and assigned custom field values(mention bellow):

```
   Post Name        Assigned Fields
1. Chalet Austria   Beachfront
2. Antoinette       Cook Services
3. Soline           Garden
4. Apoline          Private Pool
5. Alexandra        Sea View
```

After that I have created one custom field using with advance custom field plugin, and custom field name is `features`.

In features there is five option value:

```
1. Beachfront
2. Cook Service
3. Garden
4. Private Pool
5. Sea View
```

**Note: Value and text is same.**
Now I am trying find all posts that have post_type of 'villa' and value is 'Beachfront, Cook Services, Garden, Private Pool and Sea View'.

**My Code is:**

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'villa',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'features',
                'value' => '%Beachfront%',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'features',
                'value' => '%Cook Services%',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'features',
                'value' => '%Garden%',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'features',
                'value' => '%Private Pool%',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'features',
                'value' => '%Sea View%',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

When I run this code I am not getting anything, only page is reloading.. reloading.. and reloading.. :(

**I am expecting this result:**

- Chalet Austria
- Antoinette
- Soline
- Apoline
- Alexandra

Comment: Could you add the following code:

`print_r( $the_query );`

below:

`$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );`

and post the results that are output to your screen on the page.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, you should use `wp_reset_postdata` when using `WP_Query`, `wp_reset_query` is for `query_posts` which you should never use